# Markers won't show on Google Map, markers coordinates from jquery $.get call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting data like from a mysql database and JSONifying it through laravel/php accessed via `$.get`, using jquery, it returns like this:

```
[{"id":45,"name":"Aberdeen","latitude":"-2.09410800","longitude":"57.15502200"},
{"id":46,"name":"Bangor","latitude":"-4.18029020","longitude":"53.20660020"},
{"id":47,"name":"Bath","latitude":"-2.36205010","longitude":"51.38600160"}]
//list goes on
```

Then I want to add markers on my map, with a click listener which worked when I defined the above array manually in the js file and wasn't using `$.get`. With the `$.get` my code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function initialize(clubs) {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.206845, -2.422000),
            zoom: 6
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
            marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < clubs.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(clubs[i]['latitude'], clubs[i]['longitude']),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(clubs[i]['name']);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    console.log('clicked on marker');
                    $('#club-info').html('club: ' + clubs[i]['name']);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        } // end for
    } // end function initialize

    $.get(
        'api/clubdata',

    function (data) {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(data));
    });
});
```

HTML is like this (using bootstrap for style):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="club-info"></div>
</div>
```

I can't seem to figure out why the markers don't show, any help is much appreciated!

Edit:
I'll just add that the data is coming through fine, I've checked through console.log. I feel this is an issue with the way I've programmed it.

Comment: What if you log `clubs[i]['latitude']` in your `for` loop?

Comment: Also `marker = ...` should read `var marker = ...`

Comment: I actually removed that line from the start of my for loop from the code when I pasted it - lol. Yeah it shows a list of all the lats

Comment: will writing `var marker =` make a difference compared to `marker =`?

Comment: I suggest you try it.

Comment: Okay I figured it out, I got long and lat mixed up - So sorry I wasted your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass arguments in with a function pointer to the addDomListener call:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(data));
```

Do this instead:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {initialize(data)});
```

But... you really should do that in the call back to the $.get call (when the data is available).

```
$.get(
    'api/clubdata',
    function(data){
        initialize(data);
    }
);
```

You also have your longitude and latitude properties misnamed in your JSON. Should be:

```
var data = [{
    "id": 45,
        "name": "Aberdeen",
        "longitude": "-2.09410800",
        "latitude": "57.15502200"
}, {
    "id": 46,
        "name": "Bangor",
        "longitude": "-4.18029020",
        "latitude": "53.20660020"
}, {
    "id": 47,
        "name": "Bath",
        "longitude": "-2.36205010",
        "latitude": "51.38600160"
}];
```

[fiddle (without the JSON get)](http://jsfiddle.net/Wj5Eg/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot - fyi: it did work the way I wrote it though.

Comment: It might work with small amounts of data, but if the onload event fires before the data is back, the initialize function will never run.  And the only reason it "works" is because the syntax you are using doesn't wait for the onload event, it runs the initialize function and assigns its return value (null) as the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Had one of those dumb moments - Longitude and Latitude were mixed up. Should have been written like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(clubs[i]['longitude'], clubs[i]['latitude']),
                map: map
            });
```

Comment: If that is the case you should rename your longitude and latitude properties to be correct.  The google.maps.LatLng constructor takes its arguments in the order Latitude,Longitude.

Comment: Oh okay - no wonder I couldn't work it out to begin with - thank so much

Comment: @geocodezip put this as the answer and I'll mark it correct